Java Generics Warnings
I've been studying generics in Java, and after learning from various sources, I attempted to build a generic class that accepts a Number or its subclass during instantiation. This class includes a method that takes a user-created list of the same type and multiplies each value by 2, maintaining the original type, and then returns the modified list. However, I'm encountering issues with the code.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

class GenericMultiplier<T extends Number> {

    public List<T> multiplyByTwo(List<T> list) {
        List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T item : list) {
            // Perform multiplication based on the type of Number
            if (item instanceof Integer)
                resultList.add((T) Integer.valueOf(item.intValue() * 2));
            else if (item instanceof Double)
                resultList.add((T) Double.valueOf(item.doubleValue() * 2));
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 87, 34);

        GenericMultiplier<Integer> multiplier = new GenericMultiplier<>();
        List<Integer> doubledList = multiplier.multiplyByTwo(intList);

        System.out.println("Original List: " + intList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List: " + doubledList);
    }
}


Although the code is compiling correctly but I'm getting warnings such as
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Double to T
or
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Integer to T
Please help to mitigate these warnings.

you can suppress warning @SuppressWarnings annotation. @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public  T castToType(Object object) {
return (T) object;
}

As far as I can see, the cast should be safe. Since both Integer and Double are final classes, they cannot be extended. So if we enter one of the if-branches, we know that T is either Integer/Double or Number. Thus, suppressing as @SajidMehmood mentioned should be fine. --- Notice, however, that more classes extend Number (docs.oracle.com). I am also not a fan of the instanceof-cascade...

So SupressWarnings is the only viable option that can be used for Integer,Short,Byte,Double,Float, but how to handle other types such as BigInteger,BigDecimal that are subclass of Number ?

hi @GOURABMUKHERJEE
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is the right viable option in this case.
Mostly, Compiler allows this cast to preserve backward compatibility with older Java versions that do not support generics(before 1.5).

Number is not a great example of how to use generics in this case, because the interface is extremely limited: it doesn't provide the methods you need to implement your use case, so you need to distinguish between concrete classes, which is basically the anti-thesis of generics: whenever you have a method where you have to do something like in your multiplyByTwo method you'll be breaking the automatic type safety of generics. You might get away with "manually" fixing it with unsafe casts, but that's on you and that's what the warning is telling you. And a third-party Numberwould break.

Ok now I got it., Thanks for all the help

It’s all a matter of choosing useful abstractions. Making a method for a “common” operation where the type dependent operations have nothing in common, is not useful. Compare with List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 87, 34); intList.replaceAll(i -> i * 2); List<Double> dblList = Arrays.asList(1.5, 42.0, 0.6, 8.7, Math.PI); dblList.replaceAll(d -> d * 2); The common part is how to iterate and update the list, the arithmetic part, however, is different for double and integer, even when looking the same source code-wise.

You need wildcard operator for this;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class GenericMultiplier {

    public List<Number> multiplyByTwo(List<? extends Number> list) {
        List<Number> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Number item : list) {
            // Perform multiplication based on the type of Number
            if (item instanceof Integer)
                resultList.add(Integer.valueOf(item.intValue() * 2));
            else if (item instanceof Double)
                resultList.add(Double.valueOf(item.doubleValue() * 2));
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Number> numberList = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 87L, 34, 3.5);
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6);
        List<Double> dobuleList = Arrays.asList(3.5);

        GenericMultiplier multiplier = new GenericMultiplier();
        List<Number> doubledList1 = multiplier.multiplyByTwo(numberList);
        List<? super Integer> doubledList2 = multiplier.multiplyByTwo(intList);
        List<? super Double> doubledList3 = multiplier.multiplyByTwo(dobuleList);

        System.out.println("Original List 1: " + numberList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List 1: " + doubledList1);
        
        System.out.println("Original List 2: " + intList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List 2: " + doubledList2);
        
        System.out.println("Original List 3: " + dobuleList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List 3: " + doubledList3);
    }
}


This is true, but I think the point of the question was that passing a List<Integer> should return a List<Integer>; passing a List<Double> should return a List<Double>; etc. Furthermore, a parameter of List<Number> will not even accept an argument of List<Integer> or List<Double>. By changing both the type of the input and the type of the output, this answer misses the point of the question.

@jaco0646 If you want to pass List<Integer> or List<Double> to multiplyByTwo method of GenericMultiplier then you should use ? (wildcard operator).
If you use List<? extends Number> list as a parameter type then you are going to see that multiplyByTwo method accepts  List<Integer> or List<Double>

@jaco0646 I edited my answers according to your correction

I think there will always be a design problem because of the type-checks and casting the generic method. Ideally, since we are specifying the type to the generic type when we instantiate it, we should also (be forced to) provide a way to double/multiple a value of the target type in a type-safe manner.
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class GenericMultiplier<T extends Number> {

    private final UnaryOperator<T> multiplier;

    public GenericMultiplier(UnaryOperator<T> multiplier) {
      this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    public List<T> multiply(List<T> list) {
        List<T> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (T item : list) {
            resultList.add(multiplier.apply(item));
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 4, 6, 87, 34);
        GenericMultiplier<Integer> intMultiplier = new GenericMultiplier<>(x -> x * 2);
        List<Integer> doubledIntList = intMultiplier.multiply(intList);
        System.out.println("Original List: " + intList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List: " + doubledIntList);

        List<Double> doubleList = Arrays.asList(1.1, 4.4, 6.6, 87.5, 34.1);
        GenericMultiplier<Double> doubleMultiplier = new GenericMultiplier<>(x -> x * 2);
        List<Double> doubledDoubleList = doubleMultiplier.multiply(doubleList);
        System.out.println("Original List: " + doubleList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List: " + doubledDoubleList);

        BigInteger TWO = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
        List<BigInteger> bigIntegerList = Arrays.asList(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger.ONE, TWO, BigInteger.TEN);
        GenericMultiplier<BigInteger> bigIntegerMultiplier = new GenericMultiplier<>(x -> x.multiply(TWO));
        List<BigInteger> doubledBigIntegerList = bigIntegerMultiplier.multiply(bigIntegerList);
        System.out.println("Original List: " + bigIntegerList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List: " + doubledBigIntegerList);

        List<Number> numberList = Arrays.asList(1, 2.2, BigInteger.TEN);
        UnaryOperator<Number> intDoubleBigIntMultiplier = x -> {
            if (x instanceof Integer)
                return Integer.valueOf(x.intValue() * 2);
            else if (x instanceof Double)
                return Double.valueOf(x.doubleValue() * 2);
            else if (x instanceof BigInteger)
                return ((BigInteger) x).multiply(TWO);
            else
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type: " + (x != null ? x.getClass() : null));
        };
        GenericMultiplier<Number> numberMultiplier = new GenericMultiplier<>(intDoubleBigIntMultiplier);
        List<Number> doubledNumberList = numberMultiplier.multiply(numberList);
        System.out.println("Original List: " + numberList);
        System.out.println("Doubled List: " + doubledNumberList);
    }
}

When I compile and run:
$ javac -Xlint:unchecked GenericMultiplier.java

$ java GenericMultiplier                      
Original List: [1, 4, 6, 87, 34]
Doubled List: [2, 8, 12, 174, 68]
Original List: [1.1, 4.4, 6.6, 87.5, 34.1]
Doubled List: [2.2, 8.8, 13.2, 175.0, 68.2]
Original List: [0, 1, 2, 10]
Doubled List: [0, 2, 4, 20]
Original List: [1, 2.2, 10]
Doubled List: [2, 4.4, 20]

